# Automatic Migration command not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automatic-migration

So I'm doing an application using the MVC5 framework, and I have the default tables from the individual user accounts. 
Now i am trying to add my own tables,but it doesn't seem to be working.

A test class:

```
 public class teste
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Nome { get; set; }

    }

    public class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<teste> testes { get; set; }

    }
```

then i use the `add-migration` command followed by the `update-database`.
it says it updates just fine, but no table is created. am I doing something wrong ?

**EDIT**:

migration (i dunno why its empty)

```
 public partial class teste2 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
```

**EDIT2**:

*I have 2 connection strings*, one for the Authentication database (created by MVC) and the other one for my context. and the name matches the class of the `DbContext`.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ESW_Proj-20141217061426.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ESW_Proj-20141217061426;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Entities"  connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Entities.mdf;Integrated Security=True"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Can you put here migration?

Comment: Are you using Code-First ?

Comment: yep i am. edited the original post to include the migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should dedicate the target connection string name for derived `DbContext` class in constructor like this:

```
public class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities() : base("Entities") { }

    public DbSet<teste> testes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yea that worked. i found out now that i could just add new tables under the  ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> class. But i need to use the foreignKey for the ASP.netUsers witch is a varchar :O